Some episodes of DVD don't play on VLC under 24.04
I have been a long time user (over 25 years) of Ubuntu. My laptop has only Ubuntu as an OS and I recently upgraded to 24.04. and have not had any serious issues with the upgrade.
I decided yesterday to revisit my "The Wire" DVD's. As my laptop doesn't have a built-in DVD-Player I am using a USB DVD-Player. I have watched all of these DVD#s earlier on this laptop, using this DVD-Player under Ubuntu and under Wayland. Yesterday I inserted the first DVD and opened it using VLC. The menu screen came up and I selected "Episodes" and three episodes were presented. I clicked on the first one and a short description of the episodes was displayed, I clicked on "Play Episode" but it just kept returning to the description. Finally I went back to the main menu and selected the second episode, the description came up and when I clicked on "Play Episode" the episode played. The third episode played too.
Today I put in the second DVD with episodes 4-6. Whe I try and play the first episode on the DVD the same thing happens as with the first episode on the other DVD described above. The other two episodes on this DVD play normally.
I have reinstalled VLC,libdvd-pkg and ubuntu-restricted-extras but I am at a loss as to why the first episodes of each  DVD fail to play. Does anyone have any ideas?

For various values of 5, Within 5 minutes of the event, the terminal command sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes" will show system logs that cover the event.  Each log message starts with a timestamp, the host that issued the log entry, the process name, the PID in [] of the issuer and a colon (:). Everything after the colon is a message from the programmer, intended to help the user understand the program's behavior. Read man logger, for a clearer explanation.

Cause could be any one of the following:  1. Missing Codecs
2. Corrupted Video File
3. Unsupported Video Format
4. Incorrect Video File Extension
5. Hardware Acceleration Issues
6. Outdated VLC Version
7. Corrupt VLC Configuration
8. Subtitles and Overlays
9. Permissions Issue

@rob grune 1)If codecs are missing why do the other episodes on the same DVD play? 2)This is a bought DVD, how can the file be corrupted ecept by dirt and scratches? Neither of which apply. (Especially not to both DVD's) 3)See 1 above. 4) See 2 above. 5) Possible, I suppose. How to fix it? 6) I wrote in the OP that I reinstalled VLC,libdvd-pkg and ubuntu-restricted-extras, of course I didn't choose an old version. 7) see 6 above. 8) What? 9) See 1 above.

hmm, a most unusual situation. Are you sure the DVD hardware has no faults? Suggest you bypass the dvd menu and use file manager to open the video files on the disk directly. The directories should be labelled akin to 'VIDEO_TS' and the files VTS_01.VOB. If this fails, you could have a hardware problem. You could also use this method to check the properties for codecs.

@rob grune I think your suggestion that the DVD_Player is at fault is a good possibility. The VIDEO_TS directory opens and the BUP, IFO and BOP files seem to be all present, but I will see if I can borrow another DVD-Player before I rule out that possibility.

I meant VOB not BOP

suggest you try to copy all files to a hard drive. if fail, your dvd hardware is kaput.

@rob grune If the DVD-Player is faulty and not reading some sectors properly, the resulting copied files will also be corrupted. I think the best solution to test the theory that the hardware defective is to try the DVD's with another DVD-Player. I might need some time to find someone with such antiquated hardware ;-)

I bought a brand new DVD-Player and the problem remains the same, ie the first episode of a DVD will not play. So Hardware seems not to be the problem.

The problem seems to be the DVD Menu, if I run the DVD with the box "No disc menus" checked the first episode plays.
